# Zapier Scripting - Error: Cannot find module 'moment'

Tags: zapier

I'm trying to use `Moment.js` library in Zapier. The documentation says that it's available. However, when I add this line:

`var moment = require('moment');`

I keep getting this error:

`Bargle. We hit an error creating a run javascript. :-( Error: 
Error: Cannot find module 'moment'`

If I remove the declaration, I get `ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moment` is not available in https://zapier.com/help/code/ - maybe you are thinking of https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/scripting/?

I can understand how one could confuse the two - but one is a simple code step in a Zap, the other is how partners developer applications on Zapier.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!

Answer (score 2):

Moment library is available in Zapier, no need to call(require) it. Here's a snippet of code where I have used it.

```
    var date;
    if (outbound.Date === undefined) {
        var d = moment();
        var n = d.format();
        date = n.split('.');
        outbound.Date = date[0];
    }
```